# Scala XML parsing with real-world HTML (with unmatched tag)

Tags: html, xml, scala

My application is trying to embed an html document into an XML document.

```
val xml = 
  <document>
    <id> { getId } </id>
    <content> 
      { getContent }
    </content>
  </document>
```

getId is a simple function to return a new sequence number.
The issue is on getContent:

```
def getContent = {
  val wrapped = "<wrap>"+article.content+"</wrap>"
  XML.loadString(wrapped).child
}
```

As you may see, article.content return a String that stored the real-world HTML document.
The Scala.xml.XML.loadString function would parse it into XML and return a list of child and embeded into the xml val correctly.

However, this is working when only the html is valid, e.g. `<body>Hello world</body>`

In some of the article, it may appear: `<body><strong>Hello world</body>`
which lacking a closing tag of `<strong>` elem. (Yes, I can't just blame the user!)

In this case, it will throw an exception on this parsing and stop the application.

Is there any way I can either bypass the validation or simply embed the HTML as string within the XML document without parsing?

Please shed some light on this situation. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: You should use `html` parser, not `xml` parser. I prefer [Tag Soup](http://blog.dub.podval.org/2010/08/scala-and-tag-soup.html). You could parse html string to `scala` `xml` like this: `new scala.xml.parsing.NoBindingFactoryAdapter().loadXML(source, new org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.jaxp.SAXFactoryImpl().newSAXParser())`

Answer (score 2):

Both JSoup and TagSoup (amongst others) are suitable for passing HTML that isn't also well-formatted XML.

You'll have to decide which is best for your own use-case.

Comment: For TagSoup, below links is useful for reference.   http://blog.dub.podval.org/2010/08/scala-and-tag-soup.html